# How to fix rendering error in Android Studio layout preview with JWPlayerView?

Tags: android, jwplayer

I have simple layout containing JWPlayerView inside fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/gray"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.JWPlayerView
    android:id="@+id/jwplayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

But Android Studio 2.0 unable to render it in its Preview view.
Instead it shows this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.JWPlayerView.setLayoutParams(SourceFile:528)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3524)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3380)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3356)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:759)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
```

Does anybody knows how to fix it?